# PSQL : Update a table in which a trigger is also used on

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql

What is the best way to go around this.

So I use a trigger on a table. The function related to the trigger updates the same table that the trigger is used on.

This is a problem because it cannot do both.

Answer (score 1):

recursive triggers are a possible, but you should to protect self against unfinished recursion. Post your code, please.